# update_post_meta doesnt update template

Tags: plugin-development

I want to set Blank template but this function doesn't do it.Whats the problem of this code?

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'eafw_activate_insert_post' );
function eafw_activate_insert_post() {
    //create a variable to specify the details of page
    $post = array(
        'post_name' => 'dneme1111',
        'post_content'   => 'This is a example content', //content of page
        'post_title'     =>'example title', //title of page
        'post_status'    =>  'publish' , //status of page - publish or draft
        'post_type'      =>  'woocommerceareas',  // type of post
    );
    wp_insert_post( $post ); // creates page
    if ( $post = get_page_by_path( 'dneme1111', 'woocommerceareas' ) ) {
        $id = $post->ID;
    }
    update_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', 'Blank' );
}
```

Comment: Do you have a template named 'Blank'?

Comment: @TonyDjukic I have template-Blank.php and it contains <?php /* Template Name: Blank */ get_header(); ?> . "B"lank will big letter cause problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the problem of this code?

1. You incorrectly called [`get_page_by_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/) whereby if you want to specify the post type (the third parameter), then you need to specify the second parameter as well which is the return type and defaults to `OBJECT`. So:

   ```php
   // Wrong: Missing the return type (second parameter).
   // Or I mean, the third parameter "becomes" the second here.
   get_page_by_path( 'dneme1111', 'woocommerceareas' )

   // Correct.
   get_page_by_path( 'dneme1111', OBJECT, 'woocommerceareas' )
   ```

   But then, if you just want to get the ID of the newly inserted post via [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), you don't need to call `get_page_by_path()` and instead, you could simply do something like:

   ```php
   if ( $id = wp_insert_post( $post ) ) {
       // call update_post_meta() here
   }
   ```
2. Note that the value of the [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) meta has to be a ***file** name* like `template-Blank.php` <sup>(see note [1] below)</sup> and not the name of the template like `Blank` as in `Template Name: Blank`. Secondly, the template has to be in the theme folder, so the file name should be relative to that folder.

   So for example, if you have two page templates, one in the root theme folder and the other in a subfolder:

   ```
   your-theme/
     index.php
     style.css
     template-Blank.php - page template in root theme folder
     foo/
       template-bar.php - page template in a subfolder
     ...
   ```

   Then you would set the page template like so:

   ```php
   $id = 123; // post ID

   // Correct: Use the file name.
   update_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', 'template-Blank.php' );
   // Wrong.
   update_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', 'Blank' );

   // Assuming that the template has "Template Name: Bar".
   // Correct: Use the file name and relative subfolder path in this case (foo/).
   update_post_meta( 456, '_wp_page_template', 'foo/template-bar.php' );
   // Wrong.
   update_post_meta( 456, '_wp_page_template', 'Bar' );
   ```

And if you're actually trying to override the template with a custom template stored in the `wp-content/plugins` directory, then you would want to use the [`template_include` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) instead of the `_wp_page_template` metadata:

```php
// Example to override the singular template for all posts of the woocommerceareas post type.
add_filter( 'template_include', function ( $template ) {
    return is_singular( 'woocommerceareas' ) ? '/path/to/your/template-name.php' : $template;
} );
```

Or yes, you could also programmatically copy the custom template to the *active* theme folder and then use the template metadata to override the page template..

---

<sup>Note [1]</sup> For the default page template (e.g. `page.php`), you can use `default` as the meta value.

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks for your answer.I wrote this code in a plugin and the template file is in theme folder.So, must I write theme dir or stylesheet dir function before template-Blank.php?

Comment: I've revised my answer and I hope that helps?

Comment: template_include works only with add_action('init', not also with register_activation_hook( __FILE__ .I think because template_include filter is not saved on database so need the code for every time, not only register time.So, I think the only way is update_post_meta to save it to database.However, on my trying, the code didn't work with update_post_meta.What do you think about it? Thanks

Comment: maybe I can solve the problem via modify the code with get_page_by_path.I will try it later.Thanks.If I get new problem, I will comment it

Comment: Alright, but if it's a new thing or request/issue, then you should probably better off post a new question for that. And actually, `template_include` is a hook for filtering the template to be used on the current page, e.g. a single post at `example.com/hello-world`, so you don't need to hook on `init` to hook on `template_include` - i.e. you could simply call the `add_filter()` right in your main plugin file.